how to visualize collective behaviour of self propelled rod in two dimension?
multiple no. of self propelled rods (modelled using odd number of connected hard spheres ) with a fixed self propelled velocity is moving in a medium (2D) with three different diffusion constants for rotational and translational diffusions(x and y), each rod has different orientation . when two spheres of two different rods comes within a certain interaction radius a interaction force acts between them which originates from a lennard jones potential, which is function of distance between two interacting spheres. the component of the the interaction force adds up with the translation velocity and the torque which is generated rotates both the rods slowly and they starts to align .
equation of motion for the rods and the form of the potential is attachedenter image description hereenter image description here
this is the code i have written,
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.patches as patches

# Constants and parameters
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 100, 100
NUM_SPHERES_PER_ROD = 9  # Odd number of spheres per rod
SPHERE_RADIUS = 0.5
NUM_RODS = 10
VELOCITY = 2
FRAMES = 10
NEIGHBOR_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 2 * SPHERE_RADIUS  # Diameter of a sphere
EPSILON = 0.000001  # Depth of the Lennard-Jones potential well
SIGMA = 2 * SPHERE_RADIUS  # Distance at which the potential is zero


def initialize_rods(num_rods):
    positions = np.random.rand(num_rods, 2) * [WIDTH, HEIGHT]
    angles = np.random.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi, num_rods)
    return positions, angles


def update_positions(positions, angles, velocity):
    theta = angles
    dx = velocity * np.cos(theta)
    dy = velocity * np.sin(theta)
    positions[:, 0] += dx
    positions[:, 1] += dy

    # Periodic Boundary
    positions[:, 0] = positions[:, 0] % WIDTH
    positions[:, 1] = positions[:, 1] % HEIGHT
    return positions


def get_sphere_positions(start_pos, angle, num_spheres):
    sphere_positions = []
    for i in range(int((num_spheres + 1) / 2)):
        x = start_pos[0] - 2 * i * SPHERE_RADIUS * np.cos(angle)
        y = start_pos[1] - 2 * i * SPHERE_RADIUS * np.sin(angle)
        x1 = start_pos[0] + 2 * i * SPHERE_RADIUS * np.cos(angle)
        y1 = start_pos[1] + 2 * i * SPHERE_RADIUS * np.sin(angle)
        sphere_positions.append((x, y))
        sphere_positions.append((x1, y1))
    return sphere_positions


def lennard_jones_force(r):
    if r == 0:
        return 0  # Avoid division by zero
    r6 = (SIGMA / r) ** 6
    r12 = r6 * r6
    force_magnitude = 24 * EPSILON * (2 * r12 - r6) / r
    return force_magnitude


def compute_forces_and_neighbors(positions, angles):
    num_rods = len(positions)
    neighbor_sphere_pairs = []
    forces = np.zeros_like(positions)  # Forces to be applied to each rod

    for i in range(num_rods):
        sphere_positions_i = get_sphere_positions(positions[i], angles[i], NUM_SPHERES_PER_ROD)
        for j in range(i + 1, num_rods):
            sphere_positions_j = get_sphere_positions(positions[j], angles[j], NUM_SPHERES_PER_ROD)
            for sphere_pos_i in sphere_positions_i:
                for sphere_pos_j in sphere_positions_j:
                    dist_vector = np.array(sphere_pos_j) - np.array(sphere_pos_i)
                    dist = np.linalg.norm(dist_vector)
                    if dist < NEIGHBOR_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD:
                        # Record the neighbor sphere pair
                        neighbor_sphere_pairs.append((sphere_pos_i, sphere_pos_j))
                        # Calculate the Lennard-Jones force
                        force_mag = lennard_jones_force(dist)
                        force_vec = force_mag * (dist_vector / dist)  # Normalize to get direction
                        # Apply forces to the rods
                        forces[i] += force_vec
                        forces[j] -= force_vec  # Equal and opposite force

    return forces, neighbor_sphere_pairs


def update_angles(angles, forces):
    for i in range(len(angles)):
        # Compute resultant force
        resultant_force = forces[i]
        if np.linalg.norm(resultant_force) > 0:
            # Adjust angle based on resultant direction
            angles[i] = np.arctan2(resultant_force[1], resultant_force[0])
    return angles


def draw_sphere(ax, center, radius, COLOUR):
    circle = patches.Circle(center, radius, color=COLOUR, fill=True)
    ax.add_patch(circle)


def draw_rod(ax, start_pos, angle, num_spheres):
    sphere_positions = get_sphere_positions(start_pos, angle, num_spheres)
    for idx, (x, y) in enumerate(sphere_positions):
        COLOUR = "blue" if idx % 2 == 0 else "red"
        draw_sphere(ax, (x, y), SPHERE_RADIUS, COLOUR)


def animate(frame):
    global positions, angles
    positions = update_positions(positions, angles, VELOCITY)
    forces, neighbor_sphere_pairs = compute_forces_and_neighbors(positions, angles)  # Find neighbors and compute forces
    angles = update_angles(angles, forces)  # Update rod angles based on forces

    ax.clear()
    for idx, (pos, angle) in enumerate(zip(positions, angles)):
        draw_rod(ax, pos, angle, NUM_SPHERES_PER_ROD)

    ax.set_xlim(0, WIDTH)
    ax.set_ylim(0, HEIGHT)
    ax.set_aspect('equal')


# Initialize
positions, angles = initialize_rods(NUM_RODS)

# Set up the figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))

# Create the animation
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=FRAMES, interval=10, repeat=True)
plt.show()


but the rotation of the rods after interaction are not accurate . can you give any suggestion?
